# What do you call the cross that you use to manipulate a puppet?

Tags: word-request

[image]

Is there a particular word for it and what about the strings, are they just called strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Marionette controller.

The term used for the device used to control a marionette puppet (usually much more complex than just a simple cross) is, perhaps unsurprisingly,  called a "marionette controller".

I found this through a quick Google search for "marionette puppet parts" which turned up images displaying the names for different components of a marionette puppet and its controller, and a followup search for "marionette controller" turned sites such as [this shop](https://www.marionettes.cz/en-USD/control-devices-for-marionettes) that seem to confirm that name.

Answer (score 1):

The cross in the picture is the ***control bar***, and is used primarily with the kind of puppet in the picture, called a [marionette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marionette)

> Marionettes, or "string puppets", are suspended and controlled by a number of strings, plus sometimes a central rod attached to a *control bar* held from above by the puppeteer.

As far as I'm aware, the strings are just called strings.